# Terraform plan says it needs to make changes even though I haven't made any to my AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-security-group

I recently created some new resources with terraform .70 and right after running the apply I run terraform plan again and it says this needs to happen but I haven't made any changes to my main.tf file:

security_groups.#:          "0" => "1" (forces new resource)
security_groups.2319596366: "" => "sg-8a7679ec" (forces new resource)

I ran terraform apply again (on a test instance) just to see what it would do and it terminates my original AWS ec2 instance server and creates a new one (good thing I didn't do this in production)...

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Terraform thinks you've attached a new security group to your instance in terraform. Did You?

Comment: Nope it has been like that for years.  I believe aws changed how they did things which introduced a bug in terraform.  If you read my post you can see I did a plan right after the apply without making changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like .70 fixed a bug with security groups and now I have to specify security groups with vpc_security_group_ids.  I replaced security_groups with vpc_security_group_ids and it is not showing any changes are needed now.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of the `security_groups` attribute (intended for use with non-vpc, classic EC2 security groups) was changed in version 0.6.15, it no longer works properly when used with VPC security groups.  You likely need to use the `vpc_security_group_ids` attribute instead.

- Google groups discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/terraform-tool/8UeGuk1PM14/GyE21Dx8EgAJ
- Github issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6416